# Neo4j 2.0 are Cypher Queries From a Server Plug-in Cached?

Tags: performance, caching, cypher, neo4j

I know cypher queries are cached when they are executed inside a server plugin multiple times.  However, if I call the *plug-in* multiple times, does it keep the cache it accrued during previous runs?

Is there anything I need to do to make this happen?  Right now I have a parameter in my server plugin function that has a GraphDatabaseService parameter like so:

```
public Iterable<String> GetSearchResultCount( @Source GraphDatabaseService graphDb, @Description("The search criteria string") @Parameter(name = "criteria", optional = false) String criteria)
```

I use the graphdb to instantiate a single ExecutionEngine and I use both of them for all my queries in the server plug-in.  Is this enough to ensure that my queries are cached over multiple calls to the server plug-in?

I plan on warming up the cache on a nightly routine, so I'd like to make sure that the results are being cached when I call the server plug-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, holding on to a singleton for `ExecutionEngine` and `GraphDatabaseService` should have this effect.